# xgboost summation of model.apply(x) results is not equal to model.predict(x)

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm new to xgboost and I want to know the detail of its prediction process.

Here is my test case.

I find that [model.apply](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) function can get the prediction of every single tree in the xgb model. And the [model.get_booster().get_dump()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677496/how-to-get-access-of-individual-trees-of-a-xgboost-model-in-python-r) function can find the detailed decision rule as well as the score of each leaf node of every single tree.

So I write a parser to parse all the leaf node ids and its associated prediction score. Given an input data, I first use `model.apply(x)` to get the prediction of every tree, and sum them up, get `score1`. Then I use `model.predict(x)` to get `score2`. As far as I can understand, shouldn't `score1` and `score2` be equal?

Why do I get so different results?

The following is my test code.

```
import xgboost as xgb
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=5, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=500, silent=False, objective='reg:gamma')
model.load_model('my_checkpoint_file')
x = pandas_data.values
x0 = x[0:1,:]
dict_all_leaf_score = ParseLeafScore(model.get_booster().get_dump())
sum_leaf_score = 0.0
for idx, row in enumerate(model.apply(x0)[0]):
    leaf_score = dict_all_leaf_score[idx][row]
    sum_leaf_score += leaf_score
score = model.predict(x0)
print(score) # 0.32
print(sum_leaf_score) # -0.11
```

Thank you all for helping me!!

Answer (score 1):

> model = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=5, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=500, silent=False, objective='reg:gamma')

Your XGBoost regression model is using a non-linear objective function (`reg:gamma`), hence you must apply the `exp()` function to your `sum_leaf_score` value. Also, don't forget to add the base score (aka intercept).

```
score = exp(base_score + sum_leaf_score)
```

Comment: Also, some XGBoost booster algorithms (DART) use weighted sum instead of sum.

Comment: Do you mean that in this case, score1 = m.predict(x0) should be equal to exp(sum_leaf_score) ? I tried but it is not equal. And what is the base_score? I find the model has an attribute named intercept, but I called it and the program told me it is not defined in this case. Thx.

Comment: `score` should be equal to the `exp(sum_leaf_scores + base_score)`. If you don't know what `base_score` stands for, then you should ask google "XGBoost base_score".