# XGBoost Python API – accessing estimators?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, ensemble-learning

Scikit-learn's `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` (as well as other ensemble methods) stores its weak classifiers as a class attribute, in `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.estimators_`. I am trying the XGBoost package, but it seems there is no straightforward way to access the model's sub-estimators, if at all. Is there a roundabout way of accessing these estimators, or I have to modify the XGBoost codebase to store them in a class attribute variable (or if I should bite the bullet and defer to the scikit-learn implementation)?

Comment: On second thought, my idea also requires native support for NaN handling, so sklearn's GradientBoostingClassifier does not work for me. In the meantime, I am using `sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier._predictors` as a proxy, but ideally I'd be able to access XGBoost sub-estimators.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your preferred output type, you can use the `get_booster()` method to get a list of strings of each booster (credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677496/how-to-get-access-of-individual-trees-of-a-xgboost-model-in-python-r)).

Alternatively, you can use XGBoost's built-in `plot_tree()` method ([documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_tree)) to visualise each tree.