# Is it possible to collect the individual tree predictions in an XGBoost package Random Forest?

Tags: python, random-forest, xgboost

I have a model made using the xgboost package in python and I would like to know if it is possible to store and reference the individual tree predictions before they are bagged (averaged) in the case of a regression. I know how to view the actual trees, but I cannot treat each of them like a callable model to make predictions with.

```
rfr_model = xgboost.XGBRFRegressor(n_estimators = 300,
                                max_depth = 5,
                                objective='reg:squarederror')
rfr_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

when I make a prediction using X_test, I would like an output of (test rows, trees)

Answer (score 0):

In the native API, `predict` has an optional parameter `pred_leaf`; when set to `True`, the prediction is the list of node IDs from each tree that the observation gets bucketed into.  Putting that together with the dumped tree information lets us create your desired output.

```py
mf = model.get_booster().trees_to_dataframe()

dm = DMatrix(X_test)  # we're working with native API, need DMatrix

leaves = model.get_booster().predict(dm, pred_leaf=True).ravel()
leaf_scores = []
for i, leaf in enumerate(leaves):
    leaf_scores.append(mf.loc[(mf['Tree'] == i) & (mf['Node'] == leaf), 'Gain'].item())
leaf_scores = np.array(leaf_scores)
```

(I found `trees_to_dataframe` from
[How to get access of individual trees of a xgboost model in python /R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37677496/10495893).  It's a little weird, but leaf scores seem to be in the Gain column here.
And I found `pred_leaf` in
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/examples/predict_leaf_indices.html)